# iOS - disable two-finger zoom for MPMoviePlayerController fullscreen

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, gesture-recognition

How can I do this? I can't just set the userInteraction to NO, because I still need the user to be able to resize the video via pinch/zoom. I just don't want the player to ever enter fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!!

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(movieEventFullscreenHandler:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(movieEventFullscreenHandler:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification 
                                                   object:nil];

        self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    }

    - (void)movieEventFullscreenHandler:(NSNotification*)notification {
        [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
        [self.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
    }
```

Comment: That definitely does make it snap back into "non-fullscreen" mode. Still hope there's a way to prevent from going into fullscreen mode in the first place.

Comment: You could always throw some kind of UIView onto of it (loading screen or something) then remove after -movieEventFullScreenHandler is called. Kind of a hacky way to do it.